# Which one is right: "water dripping down from my knees" or "water dripping down my knees"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence

Which sentence is the right one?

> "water dripping down from my knees"

or

> "water dripping down my knees"

Is the word "from" necessary in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatically correct.

The first would imply the knees are the source of the water or at lease that there are droplets dropping directly from your knees.

The second would include water sliding down your legs, over your knees.

Comment: Hello, nachshon. Please don't embarrass a site intended for linguists by giving an answer to a question such as this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are non-native speakers using the site. Please, respect that. What could seem obvious to native speakers, maybe isn't for non-native ones.

Comment: @Renan The site is not intended for learners, but for linguists, people quite proficient in the language. ELL was set up specifically for learners / the asking of more basic questions. Please respect the stated ethos of ELU. There are many sites dedicated to helping people with basic questions. Is it right that one of the very few aimed specifically at more demanding analyses should not be afforded respect? I would not presume to ask basic questions on a site devoted to linguists in your native language (I'm assuming it's not English).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I should've read the guidelines before asking the question. I thought it was for learners.

Comment: Thanks, Renan. Please don't feel that ELU is exclusive, just not aimed at beginners. And if you look around here, you'll soon find that there are disagreements among native speakers about what is acceptable, what is preferable, how to analyse certain sentences.... ELL answers a lot of the questions learners are bound to have.